# export data from a file in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How can I export this const `data` that is received from the database to another file? I need to use this data in this other file.

```
interface Item {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

export default function Books() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getItems() {
            try {
                const { data } = await api.get("/list-results");
                setItems(data);
            } catch (error) {
                alert("error");
            }
        }
            getItems();
    },[]);
}
```

Comment: Is this all your code?  Or is this on a component?   Depending on the component relationship you can share it through properties.  You can also look into things like redux for state management

Comment: this is the code for this file, which I use only to receive data from the api. Now I need to use this data in another file

Comment: Oka, so you can do "import books from yourPathToThisFile" on you component, then call that function.  Not sure what patterns you have but I would place the api call on a separate file and have that as a simple javascript with a function that would return the data retrieved from your api.  Then on your component you can call it, you'd have the useEffect there, makes sense?

Comment: thank you, don't really need useEffect

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to the comments, I would do something like:

```
  export default async function getItems() {
     try {
       const { data } = await api.get("/list-results");
       return data;
       
     } catch (error) {
       alert("error");//not sure why you needed this
       return error
     }
    }
```

Then import this on your components.  You can then invoke it to populate the state of your components

Comment: thanks! how could you access data in the other file? importing getItems and then?

Comment: You need to call the function from it, below is an example:

import React, { useState } from 'React'
impot getItems from 'file/path/getItems';


   const Books = ()=>{

    [books, setBooks] = useState(null);

    setBooks(getItems())

    return (
    <div>{books}</div>
    )
   }